# Case statement in where clause with parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have been banging my head with this.

basically...

```
where....
and PaymentType IN CASE WHEN @PmtType = 'B' THEN ('BizPay','PerPay')
                        WHEN @PmtType = 'Z' THEN ('BizPay')
                        WHEN @PmtType = 'P' THEN ('PerPay')
                        ELSE NULL END
```

is what I'm after.  I've tried rearrangeing the CASE, putting it in parenthesis, all over here and google, I'm just not getting it to work.  Any help greatly appreacaited.  Future thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CASE Statement inside IN Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232267/using-case-statement-inside-in-clause)

Comment: Thanks, I had read that question earilier but didn't quite think it would apply to my situation.  Before bitching about referring me to something I already read I took your suggestion, read it again carefully and got it working AND I think I understand it.  Thanks again.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
   and PaymentType =CASE WHEN @PmtType = 'B' THEN 
        CASE WHEN PaymentType IN ('BizPay','PerPay') THEN PaymentType ELSE '-1' END
                    WHEN @PmtType = 'Z' THEN
                      CASE WHEN PaymentType IN  ('BizPay') THEN PaymentType ELSE '-1' END                        
                    WHEN @PmtType = 'P' THEN  
          CASE WHEN PaymentType IN  ('PerPay') THEN PaymentType ELSE '-1' END
                    ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: This almost works but I get a syntax error on the comma between ('BizPay','PerPay')

Answer (score 0):

to anyone out there wondering here was my solution

```
AND  (@PmtType = 'B' and PaymentType in ('BizPay','PerPay'))
          or (@PmtType = 'Z'  and PaymentType in ('BizPay'))
          or (@PmtType = 'P' and PaymentType in ('PerPay'))
```