# How to convert nvarchar to int inside an IN filter on a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to generate a text file, which one has a lot of filters, here it is

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Ricardo Ríos
-- Create date: 17/01/2014
-- Description: Genera el TXT para Importar a Saint
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SAINT_TXT]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        (   
        @nomina VARCHAR(MAX),
        @gerencia VARCHAR(MAX),
        @sucursal VARCHAR(MAX),
        @empresa VARCHAR(MAX),
        @departamento VARCHAR(MAX),
        @cargo VARCHAR(MAX),
        @horario VARCHAR(MAX),
        @locacion VARCHAR(MAX),
        @empleados VARCHAR(MAX),
        @desde DATETIME,
        @hasta DATETIME
        )
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @cedula varchar(max), @exnocturnas DECIMAL(5,2),
@diast DECIMAL(5,2), @diasf DECIMAL(5,0), @diasd DECIMAL(5,2),
@matut DECIMAL(5,2), @vespe DECIMAL(5,2), @noctu DECIMAL(5,2),
@linea varchar(max), @txt varchar(max),  
@l1 varchar(max),
@l2 varchar(max),
@l3 varchar(max),
@l4 varchar(max),
@l5 varchar(max),
@l6 varchar(max),
@l7 varchar(max)
SET @txt = ''

SET @nomina = (SELECT REPLACE(@nomina, '(', ''))
SET @nomina = (SELECT REPLACE(@nomina, ')', ''))
SET @gerencia = (SELECT REPLACE(@gerencia, '(', ''))
SET @gerencia = (SELECT REPLACE(@gerencia, ')', ''))
SET @sucursal = (SELECT REPLACE(@sucursal, '(', ''))
SET @sucursal = (SELECT REPLACE(@sucursal, ')', ''))
SET @empresa = (SELECT REPLACE(@empresa, '(', ''))
SET @empresa = (SELECT REPLACE(@empresa, ')', ''))
SET @departamento = (SELECT REPLACE(@departamento, '(', ''))
SET @departamento = (SELECT REPLACE(@departamento, ')', ''))
SET @cargo = (SELECT REPLACE(@cargo, '(', ''))
SET @cargo = (SELECT REPLACE(@cargo, ')', ''))
SET @locacion = (SELECT REPLACE(@locacion,'(',''))
SET @locacion = (SELECT REPLACE(@locacion,')',''))
SET @empleados = (SELECT REPLACE(@empleados,'(',''))
SET @empleados = (SELECT REPLACE(@empleados,')',''))

    declare cursor_txt cursor for
    SELECT B.ID AS cedula, 
    SUM(A.extrasnocturnas) AS extrasnocturnas, 
    SUM(A.diastrabajados) AS diastrabajados, 
    SUM(A.diasfaltantes) AS diasfaltantes, 
    SUM(A.diasdescanso) AS diasdescanso, 
    SUM(A.maturinas) AS maturinas, 
    SUM(A.vespertinas) AS vespertinas, 
    SUM(A.nocturnas) AS nocturnas
    FROM exsaint A
    RIGHT JOIN tabela B ON A.cedula = B.ID
    WHERE A.desde >= @desde AND A.hasta <= @hasta
    AND B.tipo_nomina IN (CASE WHEN @nomina = '-1' THEN B.tipo_nomina ELSE @nomina END)
    AND B.gerencia IN (CASE WHEN @gerencia = '-1' THEN B.gerencia ELSE @gerencia END)
    AND B.sucursal IN (CASE WHEN @sucursal = '-1' THEN B.sucursal ELSE @sucursal END)
    AND B.empresa IN (CASE WHEN @empresa = '-1' THEN B.empresa ELSE @empresa END)
    AND B.departamento IN (CASE WHEN @departamento = '-1' THEN B.departamento ELSE @departamento END)
    AND B.cargo IN (CASE WHEN @cargo = '-1' THEN B.cargo ELSE @cargo END)
    AND B.locacion IN (CASE WHEN @locacion = '-1' THEN B.locacion ELSE @locacion END)
    AND B.ID IN (CASE WHEN @empleados = '-1'THEN B.ID ELSE @empleados END)
    GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY ID
    open cursor_txt
        fetch next from cursor_txt into @cedula, @exnocturnas, @diast, @diasf, @diasd, @matut, @vespe, @noctu

        while @@fetch_status = 0
        begin
            SET @linea = ''
            SET @l1 = CAST(@exnocturnas AS CHAR(8))
            SET @l2 = CAST(@diast AS CHAR(8))
            SET @l3 = CAST(@diasf AS CHAR(3))
            SET @l4 = CAST(@diasd AS CHAR(8))
            SET @l5 = CAST(@matut AS CHAR(8))
            SET @l6 = CAST(@vespe AS CHAR(8))
            SET @l7 = CAST(@noctu AS CHAR(8))
            SET @linea = 
                LTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(16),@cedula)) +  
                LTRIM(RTRIM((SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @hasta, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]))) + 
                LTRIM(RTRIM('000')) + 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l1)) + @l1 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l2)) + @l2 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 3-LEN(@l3)) + @l3 )) + 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l4)) + @l4 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l5)) + @l5 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l6)) + @l6 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(@l7)) + @l7 )) +
                LTRIM(RTRIM('00000000')) +
                + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
            PRINT @txt
            PRINT @linea
            SET @txt = @txt + @linea
            fetch next from cursor_txt into @cedula, @exnocturnas, @diast, @diasf, @diasd, @matut, @vespe, @noctu
        end
    close cursor_txt
    deallocate cursor_txt

    SELECT @txt

END
```

The issue is when I pass some values to the `IN` filter I get this error.

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 5 , 4 ' to data type int.

When I execute the stored procedure like below.

```
EXECUTE SP_SAINT_TXT '-1', '-1', '-1', '( 5 , 4 )', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '20140801', '20150802'
```

Is there a way that I can add those filters with some conversions or something else and it works?

Comment: what is the datatype of column tabela.empresa ?

Comment: Are all integeres, just desde and hasta are datetime, the issue is that I wish to keep something like where empresa IN (2,3,5)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Consider using [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx) instead of parsing `varchar` parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CASE` inside `IN` statements for this task seems not possible because `CASE` only capable of returning scalar value, [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232267/using-case-statement-inside-in-clause). Also, SQL Server can't naturally deal with comma-separated value. If you can afford to change the parameter to a more appropriate data type like table parameter, that would be the ultimate solution.

Otherwise, there are some possible workaround that you can attempt to implement for this task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function). This one based on [the answer by @CeejeeB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936683/2998271). Change this part of your SQL.. :

```
AND B.empresa IN (CASE WHEN @empresa = '-1' THEN B.empresa ELSE @empresa END)
```

..to this :

```
AND (
     @empresa = '-1' 
        or 
     B.empresa IN (SELECT t.id.value('.', 'int') id FROM @empresaXml.nodes('//s') as t(id))
    )
```

The above statement always evaluates to `True` when `@empresa = '-1'`. Otherwise, `int` values will be extracted from `@empresaXml` variable and will be used to filter column `empresa`.

The variable `@empresaXml` it self declared and populated as follow :

```
DECLARE @empresaXml XML
SET @empresaXml = CAST('<s>' + REPLACE(@empresa, ',', '</s><s>') + '</s>' AS XML)
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ebed/1) :**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(empresa int, data varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES
  (1,'a'),
  (2,'b'),
  (3,'c'),
  (4,'d'),
  (5,'e')
;

Declare @empresa varchar(50) = '( 5 , 4 )'
DECLARE @empresaXml XML

SET @empresa = REPLACE(REPLACE(@empresa,'(',''), ')', '')
SET @empresaXml = CAST('<s>' + REPLACE(@empresa, ',', '</s><s>') + '</s>' AS XML)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable B
WHERE (@empresa = '-1' or B.empresa IN (SELECT t.id.value('.', 'int') id
                          FROM @empresaXml.nodes('//s') as t(id)))
```

**output :**

```
| empresa | data |
|---------|------|
|       4 |    d |
|       5 |    e |
```

Comment: Add a recommendation to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` as discussed in [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: I get this strange error now -> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_SAINT_TXT, Line 64
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: @RicardoRios what is in line 64, `SELECT B.ID AS cedula, `? Try without `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` first (If you were using it). What value you used for testing, `'( 5 , 4 )'`?

Comment: I am testing with this -> EXECUTE SP_SAINT_TXT '( 4 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 6 )','-1','-1','( 5 , 6 , 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 )','-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','20140801','20150805'   and it looks like line 64 is this one SET @XMLlocacion = CAST('<s>' + REPLACE(@locacion, ',', '</s><s>') + '</s>' AS XML)

Comment: @RicardoRios I [can't reproduce the problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ebed/2) with that parameter. The error message says `Line 64 SELECT failed...`, it is strange if you find that Line 64 doesn't have any `SELECT` there. Anyway, it is hard to diagnose if I can't reproduce the error

Comment: I've just encountered the same error in different situation. Make sure you set the flags as required : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188285%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the issue is that its treating it like a varchar, not an integer.

What you need to do is split them out, either into another table or XML. Best explained here:

[Passing a varchar full of comma delimited values to a SQL Server IN function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function)

EDIT: Link only answers are bad, so here is the method I use (from that link):

```
Declare @Ids varchar(50)
Set @Ids = ‘1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234’

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)

SELECT * 
FROM
    SomeTable 
INNER JOIN @XML.nodes('i') x(i) 
    ON  SomeTable .Id = x.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Comment: I think this is not the best way to fix these, because I have several filters, also tried the link provided, still no success

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete this using a Split function.

I use this DelimitedSplit8k function that Jeff Moden posted on SQLServerCentral in 2012 here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

You can add the Function to your database (3rd to last code box in the article) and then call it like this:

```
 AND B.empresa IN (CASE WHEN @empresa = '-1' THEN B.empresa ELSE (SELECT split.item from DelimitedSplit8k(@empresa,',') split) END)
```