# Using SQL Server CASE statement in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I want to select records from a table in a stored procedure. Given parameters can be empty or a string including some keys separated by comma (1, 2, etc)
I want to manage that when a parameter is an empty string, "WHERE" ignore searching.
I'm using this code:

```
where (CASE when @PatientID <> 0 then ( dental.ID_Sick in (1,2)) else (1=1) end)
```

Something like that is working in W3School. I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE (case when 1=1 then (Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')) else 1=1 end);
```

What is the problem in my query that does not work? SQLServerManagementStudio is giving error on "IN" statement.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh How to do?

Comment: refer to this, similar problem is explained in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232267/using-case-statement-inside-in-clause

Comment: @Shaho don't. "Dynamic" filters result in bad execution plans. If you *don't* want to use the @PatientID parameter, *don't* use the @PatientID parameter. *Don't* create such a `catch-all` stored procedure. Use an ORM like EF and LINQ if you need to use different parameters

Comment: The problem with your current syntax is you have no boolean result. A CASE **expression** is only one side of the coin. it's not a `CASE` statement, which is where you've understanding is wrong. `CASE i WHEN 1 then  'Left' ELSE 'Right' END = 'Right'` would be a Boolean result for a `WHERE`. You don't put the boolean logic in side the `WHEN`/`ELSE`.

Comment: @Shaho the server caches the execution plan of the *first* invocation. This means that if `@PatientID` is `1` the server may decide to use an index seek on `ID_Sick` even for queries that don't need it. Or for `0`, it may decide to use a table scan when an index seek on `ID_Sick` would be better

Comment: @Shaho can you provide some example closer to your actual parameters?

Comment: @Shaho what is the *client's* language? How do you intend to call that query? There are ways to create ad-hoc safely in most languages and reporting tools

Comment: @M.Ali for example think that I'm making some filters on select statement. the way is using WHERE. but my filters are not unique. in a field like Patient can be a lot of choices. but 0 means nothing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because of I'm making a stored procedure it is not possible to create query in client ...

Comment: @Shaho don't create a stored procedure and create the query in the client then. Or explain the *actual* problem so people can explain how to avoid using such CASE or `Or 1=1` statements

Comment: @Shaho for example you could use a UNION ALL of two different queries. Or use a table variable instead of `IN`. Or pass ID values as a TVP

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a very huge query that it is too hard to manage in client

Comment: @Shaho and you are making it huger by adding all those `OR` and `CASE` statements. Besides, why can't you create a *view* to simplify that query? Where is that query anyway? Using a technique that is well-known to be bad won't make the complex query easier

Comment: @Shaho besides, more complex querie are *more* susceptible to bad performance when used with "dynamic parameters" simply because there are *more* operations that can go wrong. More fields that could be covered by indexes and end up as table scans or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a `Bool` datatype, so you can't assign or return the result of a comparison as a `Bool` as you would in other languages. A comparison can only be used with `IF`-statements or `WHERE`-clauses, or in the WHEN-part of a `CASE...WHEN` but not anywhere else.

Your specific example would become this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE 1=1 OR Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')
```

Comment: Almost no database has a `bool` data type. I suspect the single exception, Postgresql, doesn't allow a return value to be used in logical operations either. What would you do with nulls? Compared against `true`, `false` or `NULL` maybe

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

The best way to handle such optional parameters is to use dynamic SQL and built the query on the fly. Something like....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
 @Param1    VARCHAR(100)    = NULL
,@Param2    VARCHAR(100)    = NULL
,@Param3    VARCHAR(100)    = NULL
,@ListParam VARCHAR(100)    = NULL
--, etc etc...
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'   SELECT * 
                FROM TableName
                WHERE 1 = 1 '

-- add in where clause only if a value was passed to parameter
        +  CASE WHEN @Param1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
           N' AND SomeColumn = @Param1 ' ELSE N'' END

-- add in where clause a different variable 
-- only if a value was passed to different parameter

        +  CASE WHEN @Param2 IS NOT NULL THEN 
           N' AND SomeOtherColumn = @Param3 ' ELSE N'' END

-- List Parameter used with IN clause if a value is passed

        +  CASE WHEN @ListParam IS NOT NULL THEN 
           N' AND SomeOtherColumn IN (
                                     SELECT  Split.a.value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(100)'') IDs
                                      FROM (
                                             SELECT Cast (''<X>'' 
                                                          + Replace(@ListParam, '','', ''</X><X>'') 
                                                          + ''</X>'' AS XML) AS Data
                                              ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes (''/X'') AS Split(a)  ' 
            ELSE N'' END

Exec sp_executesql    @sql 
                    , N' @Param1 VARCHAR(100), @Param2 VARCHAR(100) ,@Param3 VARCHAR(100) ,@ListParam VARCHAR(100)'
                    , @Param1 
                    , @Param2 
                     ,@Param3 
                    , @ListParam 


END
```

### Problem with Other approach

There is a major issue with this other approach, you write your where clause something like...

```
WHERE ( ColumnName = @Parameter  OR @Parameter IS NULL)
```

The Two major issues with this approach

1) you cannot force SQL Server to check evaluate an expression first like if `@Parameter IS NULL`, Sql Server might decide to evaluate first  the expression `ColumnName = @Parameter`so you will have where clause being evaluated even if the variable value is null.

2) SQL Server does not do Short-Circuiting (Like C#), even if it decides to check the `@Parameter IS NULL` expression first and even if it evaluates to true, SQL Server still may go ahead and evaluating other expression in `OR` clause.

Therefore stick to Dynamic Sql for queries like this. and happy days.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better readable to rewrite your statement as follows:

```
WHERE @PatientID = 0 
OR dental.ID_Sick in (1,2)
```

Referring to your actual question, I'd advise to read the linked question as provided by `B House`.

Comment: Better yet just don't use the `@PatientID` parameter at all. Such `catch all` queries result in bad execution plans

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True, but that kind of depends on the tools as used by Shaho. E.g. SSRS or C#. He might as well be learning about the concepts of t-sql and not be building an actual production tool.

Comment: But the logic of your answer is not my goal ... I have some other filters to do in that select statement.

Comment: @Shaho The use of a CASE-statement does not give you more possibilities than (nested) AND/OR constructions. Both are based on the logic IF this THEN that, where this and that are the boolean result of some statement.

Comment: @Shaho It answers the stated question.

Comment: @Shaho the attempt to create dynamic filters is the actual problem. As for the syntax error, `CASE` is *not* a logical operation. You simply can't use it this way. You'll have to use `OR`. Or, perhaps, you tried to copy code that compares the *field* to the parameter value or the field itself?

Answer (score 0):

May be this straight way will work for you

```
IF (@PatientID <> 0)
    BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Customers
       WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')
    END
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
    WHERE 1=(CASE WHEN @PatientID <>0 AND dental.ID_Sick in (1,2) THEN 1
            WHEN @PatientID =0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END)
```